# Show label of TextInputEditText when not focused on this

Tags: android, user-interface, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a layout with two `TextInputEditText` and when I set a text on this (programmatically or with `xml`) and set focus on another `TextInputEditText`, the above label of `TextInputEditText` was hidden.
I want to show this label even a text was written in this.

My `xml` code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/whiteGray2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/CustomBorderTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/oldCount"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/gray_text">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:text="Hi How are you"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/CustomBorderTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/newCount">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/newCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
            android:hint="@string/newCount"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My style:

```
 <style name="CustomBorderTextInputEditText" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

[image: I n]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
```

Remove `android:textColorHint` in the `TextInputEditText` and the use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      app:hintTextColor="@color/colorSecondary"
      android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_hint_selector"
```

The **`hintTextColor`** is the color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active.

The **`android:textColorHint`** is the color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled).

Just an example:

[image]

And this is the selector:
[image]

Here the `TextInputLayout`:

Without text:
[image]

Focused:
[image]

With text not focused:
[image]

Disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Add it in your xml code :**

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

or

**Add it in your java code :**

```
 EditText newCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newCount);
 newCount.setFocusable(true);
```

may be it usefull to you, just try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked this now but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I should add `textColorHint` and set a color instead of add `hintTextColor` attribute. But now I am confused, What is the difference between both of them?